# Не могу перейти на нужный адрес

Tags: node.js, axios

Проблема связана с разделением server.js файла на модули. Я работаю на просмотрщиком(viewer) платформы autodesk.forge и по [документации](https://forge.autodesk.com/developer/learn/viewer-app/overview) создал этот просмотрщиком.
Для создания сервера используется express и axios(ну и другие технологии, но проблема связано с упомянутыми технологиями). Так же создал папку public, в ней html файл с гиперссылкой аутентификации.

Ниже приведу рабочий код.

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');           
const Axios = require('axios');               
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
const querystring = require('querystring');



let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); 


const config = require('./config');

const PORT = config.credentials.PORT;

app.set('port', 3000);
let server = app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); });




let access_token = '';


if (process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_ID == null || process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET == null) {
    console.error('Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables.');
    return;
}


app.get('/api/forge/oauth', function (req, res) {
  Axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: querystring.stringify({
      client_id: config.credentials.client_id,
      client_secret: config.credentials.client_secret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      scope: config.scopes.internal
    })
})
    .then(function (response) {
      // Success
      // let's save token into the varible access_token
      access_token = response.data.access_token;
      console.log(response);
      // Then, the app is routed to, which creates a shared bucket for our app.
      res.redirect('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/create');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // Failed
      console.log(error);
      res.send('Failed to authenticate');
    });
});
```

```html
<body>
    <main id="main">
        <a href="/api/forge/oauth">Authorize me!</a>
    </main>
</body>
```

После дробления этого кода на модуль он перестаёт работать, вот изменённый server.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');           
const Axios = require('axios');               
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
const querystring = require('querystring');



let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); 


const config = require('./config');

const PORT = config.credentials.PORT; 


app.use('/api/forgee', require('./routes/oauth'));
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
});


let server = app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); });
```

А вот его модуль oauth.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const Axios = require('axios');
const querystring = require('querystring');        

const config = require('../config');

let router = express.Router();
let access_token = '';


if (process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_ID == null || process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET == null) {
    console.error('Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables.');
    return;
}


router.get('/api/forge/oauth', function (req, res) {
  Axios({
    
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    data: querystring.stringify({
      client_id: config.credentials.client_id,
      client_secret: config.credentials.client_secret,
      grant_type: 'client_credentials',
      scope: config.scopes.internal
    })
})
    .then(function (response) {
      // Success
      // let's save token into the varible access_token
      access_token = response.data.access_token;
      console.log(response);
      
      res.redirect('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/create');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // Failed
      console.log(error);
      res.send('Failed to authenticate');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Разделённый на модули код работает так: сервер запускается на порту 3000, появляется страницы гиперссылкой, после нажатия на неё открывается страница с текстом "Cannot GET /api/forge/oauth".
Я проверял и убеждался, что модуль oauth.js подключён к основному файлу, но почему axios не может найти страницу /api/forge/oauth я не понимаю.

У меня файл сервера работает без проблем, но когда дроблю на модули появляются проблемы.

Comment: Странно видеть упоминание о себе в мужском роде, от профиля с женским именем ..

Comment: открываешь с локального компа или по сети? в консоле браузера ошибки или предупреждения имеются?

Comment: @slippyk, открываю на локал хосте, в консоли выдаёт  Refused to load the font  'data:application/font-woff2;base64"  because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

oauth:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогли братья из тостера, вот решение.

> Замените "router.get('/api/forge/oauth'.." на "router.get('/oauth'..." в oauth.js
>   И app.use('/api/forgee', require('./routes/oauth')); на app.use('/api/forge', require('./routes/oauth'));

Иначе у вас получается URL "/api/forgee/api/forge/oauth"